# Retrieving email from POP3 server for multiple addresses and storing for local users

Tags: email

I have about 20 email users with accounts on our web host's POP3 server who are getting bombarded with hundreds of spam emails every day.  I setup an Untangle box to deal with the spam, and it does a really good job of getting rid of most of the junk.  The problem is, that throughout the night they receive so much spam that when they attempt to get their email, in the morning it can sometimes take literally hours for all of the messages to be scanned and then delivered to the inbox.

What I'd like to do is setup a server to continually get the mail from the web host's POP3 server and store it until the user retrieves it and hopefully avoid the bottleneck of having to filter hundreds or thousands of messages in the morning.

I think I can use MailUtils to get the mail from the remote server, but where I fall short is how to store the mail locally and be able to have the users get their mail from the local server.  It seems logical that I'll have to setup a POP3 server for the users to get the stored mail, but how do I "transfer" (for lack of a better term) the mail into my local POP3 server after I've pulled it from the remote server?

Comment: With 20 email users and troubles with your email provider, you might want to consider running your own mail server on a virtualised host, where you can set up the spam filtering to your liking and preferred timing.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, you are looking for `fetchmail` program. It can fetch mails from POP3, KPOP, IMAP, and so on accounts and give they to the local SMTP server for delivery. On this SMTP server you can have a SPAM filters...

You can set it to work as a daemon and it can fetch mails, say, every 5 minutes... Use `-d nr_of_secs` flag on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  I have been looking into the virtual/dedicated server avenue and I think it's the best long-term solution, but our web guy is dragging his feet getting the site ready for the move to a new server.

After reading more on fetchmail, I understand how it will work for retrieving the mail from the remote server, but how do I then prepare the mail for local retrieval by the users?  That's the part I'm stumped by.

Thanks again, guys!

Jeff

Comment: You will have mails on the local server and then you can use POP3 or IMAP server to allow retrieve it for local users.